# Fitting a list of lm models using plyr

Tags: r

Followed the guides of http://nicercode.github.io/2014-02-13-UNSW/lessons/40-repeating/ for creating a list of models.

However, it seems that I do not succesfully manage to do the split by (in this case var). See below for code example.

```
t <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3, 22,23)
a <- c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "QWE", "QWE")
data <- data.frame(a, t, y)

model <- function(x){
     lm(y~log(t),data=data)
}

fit <- model(data[data$a == "ABC" ,])
coef(fit)
```

Giving me below result:
(Intercept)      log(t) 
  -3.726673   14.335976

```
fitted.linear.model <- dlply (data, .(a), model)
ldply(fitted.linear.model, coef)
```

Giving me below result:

a (Intercept)   log(t)

1 ABC   -3.726673 14.33598

2 QWE   -3.726673 14.33598

Appreciate your help,
Newbie R coder

Comment: Where exactly is the problem here? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a value to a function you need to use it by it's "formal" name inside the function.

```
model <- function(x){
     lm(y~log(t),data=x)
}
```